# R ifelse with match

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, match

I have a dataframe 'df' that looks like this:

| LatName | ComName |
| --- | --- |
| Todd Smith | Becky Jones |
|  | Becky Jones |
|  | Becky Jones |
|  |  |
|  | Rachel Adams |

And another dataframe 'df2' that looks like this:

| LatinName | CommonName |
| --- | --- |
| Brad Robbins | Becky Jones |
| Steve Reisen | Rachel Adams |
| Connor McDougal | Charlie Williams |

If want to match values in ComName and CommonName and if they match fill in LatName with LatinName only if LatName is empty to begin with. If LatName isn't empty, then I want that entry left alone, so that the end result of df looks like this:

| LatName | ComName |
| --- | --- |
| Todd Smith | Becky Jones |
| Brad Robbins | Becky Jones |
| Brad Robbins | Becky Jones |
|  |  |
| Steve Reisen | Rachel Adams |

I left the blank row in there on purpose because some of my rows have nothing in them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do a join and then `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ComName" = "CommonName")) %>%
   mutate(LatName = coalesce(na_if(LatName, ""), LatinName)
```

-output

```
    LatName      ComName
1   Todd Smith  Becky Jones
2 Brad Robbins  Becky Jones
3 Brad Robbins  Becky Jones
4 Steve Reisen Rachel Adams
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(LatName = c("Todd Smith", NA, NA, NA),
 ComName = c("Becky Jones", 
"Becky Jones", "Becky Jones", "Rachel Adams")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(LatinName = c("Brad Robbins", "Steve Reisen", 
"Connor McDougal"), CommonName = c("Becky Jones", "Rachel Adams", 
"Charlie Williams")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This appears to work just fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was getting an issue with fields not populating like they're supposed to. So I changed LatinName to LatName and it worked, except it placed the ComName column at the end of the dataframe and gave all non-matching cells NAs instead of just leaving the non-matching cells alone. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jacob `coalesce` works by returning the first non-NA in each row and if there are both NAs, it returns NA.  Can you show an example where it is having trouble (using `dput` so that I get the structure correctly).  Also, do you have real NA or some quoted `"NA"`?

Comment: @Jacob Is there any possiblity that the 'CommonName' in 'df2'  is slightly different from 'ComName' in df1' i.e. `df2$CommonName[2] <- "Rach Adams";
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ComName" = "CommonName"))` returns NA for LatinName

Comment: @Jacob I meant `dput` of a sample of rows which may have an issue.  The `LatinName = NULL` is to remove the column as you don't need that column.  For `dput`, you can take `dput(head(df1, 10))` or `dput(head(df2, 10))` or the rows you may think have an issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247758/discussion-between-jacob-and-akrun).